# In JMeter, can you specify variables to fill in for an HTTP Request Default?

Tags: jmeter

I'd like to be able to read a value out of a CSV file, or more ideally a `.properties` file with JMeter, and then use it in multiple `Test Plan`s in the `HTTP Request Defaults` as the `Server Name or IP`, and the `Port Number`/

I wanted to set it up that way so that for a folder of different `Test Plans` that can be run, and there can be a single point of modification for any of the tests that can be run.  But the `${}` variables don't seem to populate in the `HTTP Request Defaults`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with user-defined properties. The values for those user-defined properties can be controlled from a file. In the following example, I am controlling the environment the script needs to run against by a user defined property called env.

[image: Defining a property]

And then, I am using it in the http request defaults. You can do this for any property that you want to

[image]

Comment: To get these property value from a file local to the project it looks like I'll need to use this: http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/