# Why do the reading of local property files in JMeter require a plugin?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I was [earlier looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576801/in-jmeter-can-you-specify-variables-to-fill-in-for-an-http-request-default) for a way to read properties from a project-local file for use in a JMeter Test Plan.

I found [a plugin](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/) that allows you to do this, but I still don't understand why this functionality isn't just supported natively by the standard distribution of JMeter.  Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the link you provide, the standard way to override properties files is to put them in user.properties.

Note you can also pass properties through command line option:

> -q

as per http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options

If that does not suit your requirement could you give more details about it ?